# Dropdown menu with arrow

Tags: javascript, html, css

Perhaps this is an easy matter, but I still couldn't find a solution. I tried following example from internet using menu arrow on drop-down. The problem is that all the sub-menus go down to the bottom (show), while should only show clicked menu's submenu.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <style>
                .sub-menu ul > li {
                    z-index:-1;
                    opacity:0;
                    display:none;
                }

                .drop {
                  display: inline-block;
                  transition: all .25s
                }

                .slicknav_nav.active li > .drop {
                  transform: rotate(180deg)
                }

                .slicknav_nav.active li > .sub-menu > ul > li{
                    z-index:1;
                    opacity:1;
                    display:block;
                }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="slicknav_menu">
            <ul class="slicknav_nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Movies</a>
                    <a class="drop">▼</a>
                    <div class="sub-menu">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">In Cinemas Now</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Coming Soon</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">On DVD/Blu-ray</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Showtimes &amp; Tickets</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Movies2</a>
                    <a class="drop">▼</a>
                    <div class="sub-menu">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">In Cinemas Now</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Coming Soon</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">On DVD/Blu-ray</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Showtimes &amp; Tickets</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(".slicknav_nav").click(function() {
                $(this).hasClass("active") ?
                $(".slicknav_nav").removeClass("active") :
                ($(".slicknav_nav").removeClass("active"), $(this).addClass("active"));
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can some one solve the problem? I hope it does not change the structure.

Comment: I try to make only part of the menu at the click that displays the contents of sub menu

Comment: What is the actual problem? Can you elaborate it further? `all the menu go down to the bottom` is not reproducible in given fiddle.

Comment: what is your expected output ? do you want to show in mouse over?

Comment: So your code here so that we can see where is the problem happened?

Comment: I tried to make just a mouse click menu on the display sub menu downward, instead of the two menus

Comment: @Vilthering what is the issue. It is unclear what you have problem?

Comment: @ketan no when i click menu Movies, should be only sub-menu in the movie that displays a sub menu, not both(Movies2 too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have couple of issues in your code:

1. Add click handler on `li` instead of `ul`.
2. Toggle `active` class on `li`.
3. In click handler, remove `active` class from all `li`s, then just add to current `li`.

**Updated Code:**

```js
$(".slicknav_nav li").click(function() {
    $(".slicknav_nav li").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}

.drop {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all .25s;
}

.slicknav_nav li.active > .drop {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.slicknav_nav li.active > .sub-menu {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slicknav_menu">
  <ul class="slicknav_nav">   
    <li>
      <a href="#">Movies</a><a class="drop">▼</a>
      <div class="sub-menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">In Cinemas Now</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Coming Soon</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">On DVD/Blu-ray</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Showtimes &amp; Tickets</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Movies2</a><a class="drop">▼</a>
      <div class="sub-menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">In Cinemas Now</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Coming Soon</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">On DVD/Blu-ray</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Showtimes &amp; Tickets</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/vtkr7ee1/)